# Create AD group using PowerShell does not work in the Orchestrator Runbook

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, orchestration

I am unable to run the PowerShell script in the System Center Orchestrator Runbook. The code works in the standalone PowerShell application, but the same code in the Runbook causes this error :

> The term 'New-ADGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have written code to check the existence of the group and if do not exists then create the AD group. The below code works in the standalone Powershell:

```
$TargetOU = "OU=Test,DC=applet,DC=com"
$GroupName = "test"

try { Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupName }
catch {
    New-ADGroup -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -Name "$Groupname" -Path: "$TargetOU" 
}
```

I am expecting to run the code in the Orchestrator Runbook to check the existence of a security group. If it does not exist, then create the security group.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are there any errors logged, or any other indication of what's happening? Any time you're testing an unattended script, things can go wrong that you don't expect. For instance, if the account that's running the script doesn't have the appropriate AD access then I'd expect this not to work.

Comment: Is the activedirectory PS module installed on the orchestrator machine? Have you tried to explicitly import the module (Import-Module ActveDirectory) in the script?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I believe the access issue. The script runs fine for other tasks like creating the folder,applying access etc. However, prompting error for the AD group access. 

I am not sure how to grant access to the Runbook service. Also, do we need to add the required permissions prompt to the script to function the task?

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld, The AD module is already installed, am able to apply the ACL permission to the folder and able to get the AD group properties from the powershell command line but not running in the Orchestrator Run book.

Comment: @Jay I believe you'd need to grant access to the service account running the script to read and create groups in the target OUs.

Comment: Hi Team,

The Solution is, the powershell version in the Orchestrator Runbook differs from the version in the host machine.

The link : http://get-cmd.com/?p=3731 provides the steps to check the current version in the Orchestrator and update to the required version.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is, the powershell version in the Orchestrator Runbook differs from the version in the host machine. The link : get-cmd.com/?p=3731 provides the steps to check the current version in the Orchestrator and update to the required version